# How to play a dvd movie in windows 8?

Tags: dvd, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing DVD movies in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/476926/playing-dvd-movies-in-windows-8)

Recently I installed Windows 8 professional. I have a strange issue. How to play a dvd with default installed software like Movie or Media Player? Both can't see my dvd drive, which works perfectly good with Best Player for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because Windows 8 doesn't come with the codecs necessary to play most DVDs by default. When Windows 8 launches, there will be an optional package you can install to enable DVD playback. In the meantime, though, you could try using free software like [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Comment: This is win 8 pro though, so it does come with media player.

Comment: @soandos It may have the media player, but the player won't have a ton of codecs (well, it may not)