# Playing DVD movies in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Does any one know how to play a DVD movie in Windows 8's default programs like Movie or Media Player? I cannot perform this action, I can't even find such an option. Even Media Player seems to ignore my inserted DVD movie: I am inserting a DVD and nothing happens.

Comment: I thing you have to install a special package to play DVDs with digital restrictive rights.

Comment: Are you expecting it to play just by inserting it. Maybe Microsoft have disabled this annoying, and sometimes dangerous behaviour. Try the play button, in one of the movie players.

Comment: No I don't. But I also noticed lack of this function.

Comment: I just noticed [a footnote](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions) that mentions this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to purchase the [Windows Media Center pack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_8#Media_features) separately in order to add DVD playback back into your OS. It will be available to Windows 8 Pro users on October 26th.

According to the Building Windows 8 Blog, *by default*, [Windows 8 does not come with DVD codecs](https://web.archive.org/web/20151114033935/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/05/04/q-amp-a-dvd-playback-and-windows-media-center-in-windows-8.aspx). This is because codec licensing costs are non-trivial, and many computers no longer come with a DVD drive in the first place.

If you're currently using Windows XP, Vista, or 7, you can [upgrade to the full Windows 8 Pro With Media Pack](http://web.archive.org/web/20121016185706/http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/07/02/upgrade-to-windows-8-pro-for-39-99.aspx) for $40. If you already have Windows 8 standard installed, you will be able to purchase a Windows 8 Pro upgrade pack through the Microsoft Store (currently [available for pre-order](https://web.archive.org/web/20151114033935/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/05/04/q-amp-a-dvd-playback-and-windows-media-center-in-windows-8.aspx)), which will enable you to install Media Center.

Media pack is not pre-installed with Windows 8 Pro. There is no official word yet on what it will cost to add the Media Pack to Windows 8 Pro separately, but it will be available as an optional add-on.

As per [this official blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/07/02/upgrade-to-windows-8-pro-for-39-99.aspx) though, Windows Media Center can be added **for free** through the *[Add Features](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs)* option within Windows 8 Pro after the $40 upgrade, at least till January 31, 2013 (that's the last date as of now for the low upgrade price, though Microsoft *may* choose to extend the date of course). Further, if the Windows 8 Pro System Builder version is installed, Windows Media Center can be added to it as well via the *Add Features* option **for free** during the promotion.

Of course, you can always purchase 3rd party DVD playback software, or use something like VLC or any other free player+codec pack combo that provides this feature.

Comment: I havent used Windows Media Player in... a *very* long time.  VLC is free and is simply the best media player there is. AS for why, MS has to license the codecs to play DVD media, it costs them money and people were not using Media Player anyway.  Check out this article:  http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/how-much-do-dvd-and-digital-media-playback-features-really-cost/4977

Comment: VLC being "the best media player there is" is entirely a matter of opinion of course, but that aside, here's a good article discussing how it can legally get away with providing DVD playback for free, to the very same users whom MS, Apple etc. would need to charge for the feature: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/if-vlc-can-ship-a-free-dvd-player-why-cant-microsoft/4962

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FFDShow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) codecs to play DVDs in WMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can install codecs for Windows Media Player, install K-Lite COdec Pack, it's good and allows DVD playback.

You can download it from [here](http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Be sure to download standard as it includes mpeg2 codecs.

> Same as Basic, plus:
>
> - Media Player Classic HomeCinema
> - MPEG-2 decoder for DVD playback
> - MediaInfo Lite