# What video files can Windows 8 play without having to download external codecs?

Tags: windows-8, codec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For which codecs/containers does Windows Media Player now have inbuilt support with Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/493847/for-which-codecs-containers-does-windows-media-player-now-have-inbuilt-support-w)

Do I still need to download and install something like K-Lite with Windows 8, or have they bundled codecs in to play the myriad of media types on the web? (.mkv, xvid, h264, etc.)

Comment: .mkv is not a codec, it's a container.

Answer (score 1):

The best overview to this question is [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919232109/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/06/08/building-a-rich-and-extensible-media-platform.aspx):

"Formats popular among the enthusiast community or with specific developers such as FLAC, MKV, and OGG, can have their own CODECs packaged as part of a Metro style app, since the Windows 8 media platform is highly extensible."

So, to play "everything" you still have to install individual codecs or packs.