# Windows 8 N & Media Player/DVD playback

Tags: windows-8, dvd, codec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing DVD movies in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/476926/playing-dvd-movies-in-windows-8)

An open-ended question (ie I havn't encountered this yet...)

Being in the UK I consider it only a matter of time until I come across the following scenario:

Windows 8 Pro N install where the End User wants DVD playback without installing all the Media Player 'add-ins' to enable it.

Will just installing codecs and then some playback software work? (ie no huge downloads from Windows Update - consider this user to only want Crtical Updates due to a slow internet connection.)

Comment: Windows 8 does not have video playback ability, unless you add the Media Center add-on, so just install a third-party video player. Of course considering its free until 2013 you should claim it.

Comment: Not exactly no... I'm talking about playback **without** adding Media Player on **N** editions. Regular vanilla 8 Pro has Media Center available as an add-in.

Comment: Ramhound, is it possible to install codec's without adding Media Center first?

Comment: External codecs have nothing to do with Media Center. Also, something like VLC (mentioned in my answer) does not even use external codecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N is without "media stuff" so as long as you find a 3rd party application that includes the relevant codecs and libraries, nothing else from Microsoft should be involved.

Answer (score 2):

Use VLC Media Player, it supports DVD playback, and is for W8

It is a stand alone player also, not dependent on Windows for much of anything than the Windows framework.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/